# Grails - Get return from my POST request HTTP

Tags: rest, http, grails, groovy, httpbuilder

I have a grails code for a POST type REST call where I pass the login parameters and it was to receive the token and an access route, it is correct, both by Postman that I get these parameters right, and by the code also after all, it does not fall no catch for error handling.

The answer I get from Posman goes something like this:

```
{
"access_token": "and ... 2",
"instance_url": "http: \ / \ / m ... \ / .. c"
}
```

This is the one excerpt from my grails code:

```
    def http = new HTTPBuilder (sf_login_domain)
    def postBody = [
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: consumer_key,
        client_secret: consumer_secret,
        username: auth_username,
        password: auth_password
    ]
    try {
        http.post (path: 'ApplyLogin', body: postBody, requestContentType: URLENC) {
          resp, json ->
            log.debug "** access_token: $ {json.access_token}, instance_domain: $ {json.instance_url}"
            access_token = json.access_token
            instance_domain = json.instance_url + "/"
        }
        returnLogin = ['access_token': access_token, 'instance_domain': instance_domain]
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error "** Error code: $ {e}"
        log.error "** Post form: $ {postBody}"
    }
```

But my debug line log.debug `"** access_token: $ {json.access_token}, instance_domain: $ {json.instance_url}"`, returns me the empty JSon parameter.

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong? If there is another way to do this call in grails, or am I getting the answer incorrectly?

**UPDATE**

I can do the post quietly by Postman, I think maybe it's because I step in the Headers parameter `Content-Type = 'application/json'`, does anyone know how to do this in grails with `HTTPBuilder`?

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

My code class.groovy completed

```
    package crm.emp

        import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
        import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
        import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
        import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
        import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
        import static groovyx.net.http.Method.PATCH
        import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

        class CrmService {

            def grailsApplication

    static transactional = true

    def login() {
        log.info "* Login"

        def sf_login_domain = grailsApplication.config.crm.sf_login_domain
        def consumer_key = grailsApplication.config.crm.consumer_key
        def consumer_secret = grailsApplication.config.crm.consumer_secret
        def auth_username = grailsApplication.config.crm.auth_username
        def auth_password = grailsApplication.config.crm.auth_password
        def retornoLogin
        def access_token
        def instance_domain

        //Request Access_token and instance domain for work
        def http = new HTTPBuilder(sf_login_domain)
        def postBody = [
            grant_type: 'password',
            client_id: consumer_key,
            client_secret: consumer_secret,
            username: auth_username,
            password: auth_password
        ]
        try {
            http.post( path : 'EfetuarLogin', contentType :JSON, body : postBody) {
              resp, json ->
                log.debug "**  json: ${json.EfetuarLogin}"
                log.debug "**  access_token: ${json.EfetuarLogin.access_token}, instance_domain: ${json.EfetuarLogin.instance_url}"
                access_token = json.EfetuarLogin.access_token
                instance_domain = json.EfetuarLogin.instance_url
            }
            coss.Parametro.executeUpdate("update Parametro p set p.valor='$access_token' where p.chave='ACCESS_TOKEN_SALES_FORCE'")
            coss.Parametro.executeUpdate("update Parametro p set p.valor='$instance_domain' where p.chave='INSTANCE_DOMAIN_SALES_FORCE'")
            retornoLogin = ['access_token':access_token, 'instance_domain':instance_domain]
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.error "** Error code: ${e}"
            log.error "** Post form: ${postBody}"
        }
        return retornoLogin
    }

    def verificaAcessoCrm() {
        log.info "* VerificaAcessoCrm - teste 29"

        def access_token = coss.Parametro.findByChave('ACCESS_TOKEN_SALES_FORCE')?.valor
        def instance_domain = coss.Parametro.findByChave('INSTANCE_DOMAIN_SALES_FORCE')?.valor

        def retornoLogin

        if(access_token && instance_domain) {

          def http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
          def postBody = [
            token_type:'Bearer',
            access_token:access_token
          ]
          try {
              http.post( path : 'VerificarAcesso', contentType:JSON, body : postBody) {
                resp, json ->
                access_token = json.VerificarAcesso.access_token
                instance_domain = json.VerificarAcesso.instance_domain
              }
              retornoLogin = ['access_token':access_token, 'instance_domain':instance_domain]
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              log.error "** Error code: ${e}"
              log.error "** Post form: ${postBody}"
              retornoLogin = login()
          }
        }else{
          retornoLogin = login()
        }

        log.debug "** RetornoLogin: ${retornoLogin}"

        return retornoLogin
    }

    def atualizaPedidoCrm(numeroCRM, dataFim, codigo, nfe, series, danfeEmitido, boletoEmitido, formaDeEnvio) {
        log.info "* AtualizaPedidoCrm"
        log.debug "**  DataFim: ${dataFim}, codigo:${codigo}, nfe:${nfe}, danfeEmitido:${danfeEmitido}, boletoEmitido:${boletoEmitido}, formaDeEnvio:${formaDeEnvio}"

        def urlOpportunity

        def verificaAcessoCrm = verificaAcessoCrm()

        def access_token = verificaAcessoCrm.access_token
        def instance_domain = verificaAcessoCrm.instance_domain

        if(access_token && instance_domain && dataFim) {
            // urlOpportunity = buscaPedidoCrm(numeroCRM, access_token, instance_domain)
            // busca o pedido com os campos da nota
            urlOpportunity = buscaPedidoCrmENfe(numeroCRM, access_token, instance_domain)
            log.info "** UrlOpportunity: ${urlOpportunity}"

            if(urlOpportunity) {

                if (urlOpportunity?.nfe1 == nfe.toString()+'-'+series.toString() ||
                    urlOpportunity?.nfe2 == nfe.toString()+'-'+series.toString() ||
                    urlOpportunity?.nfe3 == nfe.toString()+'-'+series.toString()){
                    return 0
                }
                def postBody = []

                if(urlOpportunity?.nfe1 == null || urlOpportunity?.nfe1 == ''){
                  postBody = [
                    token_type:'Bearer',
                    access_token:access_token,
                    Numero_do_pedido__c:numeroCRM,
                    Data_saida_expedicao__c:dataFim.format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                    N_Remessa__c:codigo.toString(),
                    Foi_expedido__c: true,
                    N_mero_da_Nota_Fiscal__c:nfe.toString()+'-'+series.toString(),
                    Nota_fiscal_emitida__c: danfeEmitido,
                    Boleto_enviado__c: boletoEmitido,
                    meio_envio_COSS__c:formaDeEnvio.toString()
                  ]
                }
                else if(urlOpportunity?.nfe2 == null || urlOpportunity?.nfe2 == ''){
                  postBody = [
                    token_type:'Bearer',
                    access_token:access_token,
                    Numero_do_pedido__c:numeroCRM,
                    N_mero_da_Nota_Fiscal_2__c:nfe.toString()+'-'+series.toString(),
                    N_de_Remessa_2__c:codigo.toString(),
                    Data_Sa_da_Expedi_o_Embarque_2__c:dataFim.format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                    Meio_de_Envio_COSS_2__c:formaDeEnvio.toString()
                  ]
                }
                else if(urlOpportunity?.nfe3 == null || urlOpportunity?.nfe3 == ''){
                  postBody = [
                    token_type:'Bearer',
                    access_token:access_token,
                    Numero_do_pedido__c:numeroCRM,
                    N_mero_da_Nota_Fiscal_3__c:nfe.toString()+'-'+series.toString(),
                    N_de_Remessa_3__c:codigo.toString(),
                    Data_Sa_da_Expedi_o_Embarque_3__c:dataFim.format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                    Meio_de_Envio_COSS_3__c:formaDeEnvio.toString()
                  ]
                }

                def http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
                try {
                    http.post( path : "AtualizarPedido/"+urlOpportunity.url, contentType:JSON, body : postBody) {
                      resp, json ->
                        log.info "** Status: $resp.status"
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    log.error "** Error code: ${e}"
                    log.error "** Post form: ${postBody}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def buscaDadosCrm(numeroCRM) {
        log.info "* BuscaDadosCrm - Consultar Pedido"
        log.debug "**  numeroCRM: ${numeroCRM}"

        def verificaAcessoCrm = verificaAcessoCrm()

        def access_token = verificaAcessoCrm.access_token
        def instance_domain = verificaAcessoCrm.instance_domain

        def formaDeEnvio
        def tipoVenda
        def pedidoRelacionadoCrm

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
        def postBody = [
          token_type:'Bearer',
          access_token:access_token,
          Numero_do_pedido__c:numeroCRM
        ]
        try {
            http.post( path : 'ConsultarPedido', contentType:JSON, body : postBody) {
              resp, json ->
                formaDeEnvio = json.ConsultarPedido.meio_envio_COSS__c
                tipoVenda = json.ConsultarPedido.Tipo_de_Pedido__c
                pedidoRelacionadoCrm = json.ConsultarPedido.Numero_do_pedido_na_OBS__c
            }
            log.debug "** Forma de envio: $formaDeEnvio | Tipo Venda: $tipoVenda | Pedido Relacionado: $pedidoRelacionadoCrm"
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.error "** Error code: ${e}"
            log.error "** Post form: ${postBody}"
        }

        return [formadeEnvio:formaDeEnvio, tipoVenda:tipoVenda, pedidoRelacionadoCrm:pedidoRelacionadoCrm]
    }

    /*def buscaPedidoCrm(numeroCRM, access_token, instance_domain) {
        log.info '*buscaPedidoCrm'
        log.debug "* numeroCRM: ${numeroCRM}"

        def url

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
        http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
          uri.path = 'consultarpedido/'+numeroCRM
          headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"

          response.success = { resp, json  ->
            assert resp.status == 200
            url = json.attributes.url
          }

          response.failure = { resp, json ->
            log.debug "$resp.status"
            //log.debug "$json?.errorCode"
            //log.debug "$json?.message"
          }
        }
        log.debug "*url: $url"
        return url
    }*/

    // metodo adiconada pois a Sin (Brill e Luciana) querem garvar mais de uma nota
    def buscaPedidoCrmENfe(numeroCRM, access_token, instance_domain){
        log.info "* BuscaPedidoCrmENfe - Consultar Notas"
        log.debug "** NumeroCRM: ${numeroCRM}"

        def url
        def nfe_1
        def nfe_2
        def nfe_3

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
        def postBody = [
          token_type:'Bearer',
          access_token:access_token,
          Numero_do_pedido__c:numeroCRM
        ]
        try {
            http.post( path : 'ConsultarNotas', contentType:JSON, body : postBody) {
              resp, json ->
                url = json.ConsultarNotas.attributes.url
                nfe_1 = json.ConsultarNotas.N_mero_da_Nota_Fiscal__c
                nfe_2 = json.ConsultarNotas.N_mero_da_Nota_Fiscal_2__c
                nfe_3 = json.ConsultarNotas.N_mero_da_Nota_Fiscal_3__c
            }
            log.debug "** Url: $url | Nfe1: $nfe_1 | Nfe2: $nfe_2 | NFfe3: $nfe_3 "
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.error "** Error code: ${e}"
            log.error "** Post form: ${postBody}"
        }
        return [url:url, nfe1:nfe_1, nfe2:nfe_2, nfe3:nfe_3]
    }
}
```

Comment: use also `contentType:JSON` in your options. also what are you getting on the receiving side?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know where by the contentType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the call so it looks like:

```
http.post (path: 'ApplyLogin', body: postBody, contentType:JSON, requestContentType: URLENC) {
```

UPDATE:

```
HTTPBuilder hb = new HTTPBuilder( url )
hb.request( POST, JSON ){ req ->
  uri.path = 'EfetuarLogin'
  body = [ "grant_type": "password",
           "client_id": "xxx",
           "client_secret": "yyy",
           "username": "zzz",
           "password": "*****" ]

  response.success = { resp, json -> println json }
}
```

prints out:

```
{access_token=xxx-yyy-zzz....., instance_url=some_url}
```

Comment: I already tried it and gave this error: `Error code: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Method Not Allowed`

Comment: have you imported `groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*`?

Comment: also in the postman you are sending a json-request, whereas in your groovy code you are sending URL-encoded parameters and this is NOT the same

Comment: Yes `import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON`

Comment: remove `requestContentType: URLENC` from your call

Comment: remove and I'm testing

Comment: Returned this error: `Error code: groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: Found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170092/discussion-between-injecteer-and-marcius-leandro).